# LinkedIn Marketing API

Tags: linkedin-api, linked-server

How can we Identify which post we received a comment on a LinkedIn post using a LinkedIn API?
For Example ("We have 100 Posts on are linked page now I wanted to Identify out of 100 posts which post we received a comment)

proper API or Any Alternate way of this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Posts API to [find the posts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2023-02&tabs=http#find-posts-by-authors) your organization has authored. Then, you can get a [summary of social actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/network-update-social-actions?view=li-lms-2023-02&tabs=http#batch_get-summary-of-social-actions) for a group of posts and identify which ones have comments in the `commentsSummary` object.

Comment: I already Try it this thing but they provide overall posts which are available on my LinkedIn page I just wanted to know if is there any other way to identify which posts have received a recent comment (Can you please provide the syntax of the API )